# Java Annotation Processing - Get Constructor Value

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

Is it possible to get the value of an enum constant's constructor argument within an annotation processor?

I have an enum which defines a constructor and is scanned because it is also annotated.

```
@MyAnnotation
public enum Exmaple{
    FOO("foo value"),
    BAR("bar value");

    Example(final String val){}
}
```

I'd like to be able to get the values of the constructor arguments that the constants define (i.e actually know that the constant FOO is initialized with "foo value"). Is this possible?

I can find each constant but there are no enclosed elements so the actual `TypeElement` which the enum constant is, seems to be the end of the line.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Only if you are ok with using javac's Tree API (not available in Eclipse compiler). Realistically, you are better off changing your `enum Exmaple` (for example, by annotating each enum member with separate annotation, that contains the string).

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from adding a getter for your constructor value?

Comment: Disregard previous question. When processing annotations you are traversing class meta information, so there is no real objects, method calls and arguments there. What are you trying to achieve by annotating the object? Maybe one can suggest another approach.

Comment: @AlehMaksimovich well i was just using the annotation as a means of generating metadata from source using the processing API. I'm happy to entertain other options if you know of any.  Basically, I am trying to generate a meta file from various aspects of our source. The annotation processor seemed the easiest way to do this since consumers just need to add a compile-time dependency on the processor (i.e no special build set up).  If there'a better way I'm all ears